# Difference between filtering range and table

Tags: vba, excel, filtering

Can someone explain why there is a difference between filtering a range and a table? I get the difference between the two, but I dont see why a range filter cannot filter the underlying data when its formatted as a table.

I've been having issues filtering files due to the difference. I am consolidating x number of user files with the same headers. However, some people (*thanks a lot, Charles across the hall*) decide to format as a table which is causing issues.

Is there a universal way (or more effective way) to filter data that is independent of the format? As an example, I am trying to filter for text "NORAM" in Col A, and then copy/paste visible cells elsewhere.

Do I need to do something like this?

```
If Range("A1") is range Then
    Filter Range("A1") with range method ("NORAM")
    Copy Visible Cells
    Paste to Destination
Else
    Filter Range("A1") with table method ("NORAM")
    Copy Visible Cells
    Paste to Destination
End If
```

Or is there a way to do something like this, which is independent of range or table?

```
Range("A1") filter range regardless of format ("NORAM")
Copy Visible Cells
Paste to Destination
```

I do not need help copying or pasting data. The above are just generic steps. I'm hoping to see the most effective way to filter a range, a table, and hopefully a way to filter both regardless of format.

Comment: Use the first case,
`If Range("A1") is range` should always return true. Try testing if the sheet contains a table object instead.

Comment: That wasn’t meant to be taken literally, just pushing the point that it’s not in table format. Sorry for the confusion there, good suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what error you're getting but here's a quick filter, tested on both a table (Sheet1) and a range not formatted as a table (Sheet2).

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub FilterTableOrRange(ws As Worksheet)
    Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long

    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).AutoFilter _
            Field:=1, Criteria1:="NORAM"
    End With
End Sub

Sub Master()
    FilterTableOrRange Sheets("Sheet1")
    FilterTableOrRange Sheets("Sheet2")
End Sub
```

[image]

If this is not helpful, then please specify the exact issues you've had.

Comment: Hm. So this method works regardless of how the data is formatted (which is what I wanted to know). I’ve seen methods to filter tables that is different than filtering a range, which led me to believe the methods were case sensitive (by case I mean range or table). This means my problem isn’t the filtering. Maybe it’s copying visible cells from a table/range that needs different methods? Either way, that question is off topic here so I’ll look into it further and post a new question if I can’t figure it out!